# Circle around text that extends to oval when it's long (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I'm trying to achieve the following behavior:
A circle around text that changes into oval when the text is longer than 1 digit.
Of course, should be dynamic, like on whatsapp:

[image: example]

This is what I tried but it's not the best practice as you see (The Positioned widget is because it's on stack):

```
if (num > 99) {
  return Positioned(
      right: 0,
      top: 5,
      child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          child: Container(
            width: 30,
            height: 20,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: orange,
            ),
            child: Center(child:Text("99+",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: listBackground,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular',
                )),
            ) )));
}
String value = num > 9? "9+" : num.toString();
return Positioned(
  right: 0,
  top: 5,
  child: CircleAvatar(
      radius: 10.0,
      backgroundColor: orange,
      child: Text(value,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: listBackground,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 12,
            fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular',
          ))),
);
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: check `StadiumBorder` and use it with `ShapeDecoration`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Container with padding and BorderRadius like that:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.green,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(15.0),
        ),
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 8.0),
      child: const Text('2'),
    );
  }
```

I ran it on dartpad and it looks like that:

[image: Single digit]
[image]